# Making transparent borderless windows with minimize and maximize animations

Tags: c++, windows, transparent, dwm, borderless

I want to create a transparent borderless window.
By word transparent i mean per-pixel transparency, so it has a transparent background.
It has to support minimize and maximize animations.

i tried doing so:

```cpp
MARGINS margins = { -1 };
DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea( hwnd, &margins );

DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY ncrp = DWMNCRP_DISABLED;
DwmSetWindowAttribute( hwnd, DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY, &ncrp, sizeof( ncrp ) );

LRESULT WINAPI WndProc( ... ){
    switch ( msg )
    {
        ...
        case WM_NCCALCSIZE: return 0;
    }
}
```

but i always get the same problem. non-dwm window border appears for a frame everytime i focus/unfocus the window.
here is how it looks.

[image: broken window]

removing EX_ styles doesn't fix it.